# Sorting vector using custom function that will accept vector of any type and std::less/std::greater as comparator

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, std, c++20

I'm trying to sort a vector(in this particular case containing `std::make_unique<std::string>` but it should be able to work with different types as well). Here is the code that I was provided:

```
template <typename T>
void print_vector_of_pointers(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
 for (const auto& ptr : vec) {
 std::cout << *ptr << ' ';
 }
 std::cout << '\n';
}
int main() {
 auto vec = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>();
 vec.push_back(std::make_unique<std::string>("ghi"));
 vec.push_back(std::make_unique<std::string>("abc"));
 vec.push_back(std::make_unique<std::string>("jkl"));
 vec.push_back(std::make_unique<std::string>("def"));
 print_vector_of_pointers(vec);
 auto sorted = sorted_view(vec, std::less());
 print_vector_of_pointers(sorted);
 print_vector_of_pointers(vec);
}
```

Output should be:

```
ghi abc jkl def
//abc def ghi jkl wrong, of course as you've stated it will sort the pointers, not what it actually contains
ghi abc jkl def
```

Compiler is giving me this error regardless of what I'm trying to do:

```
cannot deduce template arguments for 'less' from ()
```

And I'm not sure whether I should only write a template for function sorted_view() and write some template for std::less so it can take vector of any kind or I should also overload the () operator. Right now any trials while writing sorted_view() resulted in the compiler error as I've attached above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `std::less<>()`.

Comment: What does `sorted_view` do? does that (also) assume that you have a vector of pointers?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this is `C++17`. CTAD should kick in and the `<>` should not be required. [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/vEYYaz).

Comment: @Caleth it assumes being given a vector of unique pointers to whatever and returning a vector of raw pointers to that whatever as a view of sorted elements. For sorting, one has to use specified as a second argument comparator function.

Comment: @Fureeish does it? I don't see a definition

Comment: @Caleth what kind of definition? `std::less` template is defaulted on `void` (`typename T = void`). [This does not require any additional guides](https://godbolt.org/z/K8oTx9).

Comment: @Fureeish `sorted_view` is not defined here, and it's not in `std`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226925/discussion-between-fureeish-and-caleth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You claim to use `C++17` (since you used its tag). Most probably you have not enabled it in your project. Just add a flag that enables it, e.g. `-std=c++17` for Clang or GCC, or `/std:c++17` for MSVS.

If you are using CMake, you can just use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`.

Comment: Thank you, this actually solved the main issue so now I can finally deal with writing the template ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the compiler to deduce `std::less<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` from nothing. You will need to specify `std::less<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` to construct one, or `std::less<>` to construct a polymorphic one.

Note that `std::less<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` will not compare the strings, it will order the pointers based on an implementation-defined total order.

Ordinarily, you wouldn't use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>`, but `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: By enabling `C++17` (which OP states that they use) [one need not specify the `<>`](https://godbolt.org/z/vEYYaz).